# In Eclipse, "Update Maven Dependencies" is disabled and greyed-out, why?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I'm using Eclipse STS 2.7.1 and created a new Spring Template/MVC project. I deleted the pom file and replaced it with one from another project that has all the dependencies I need. But when I attempt to update the dependencies, the menu option is disabled...why?

[image]

Comment: Does it work when you click on `maven->update dependencies` instead of spring tools one?

Comment: Yeah, I must be blind, did not see that, thanks

Comment: No problem. I will make my comment an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Spring Tools maven option, select `Maven->Update Dependencies`. That should do the trick!